# fetching the url in php

Tags: php

my url is like below:

http://www.xyz.org/abc/list.php?id=1

now "$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']" gives me only "abc/list.php" this portion

and "$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']" gives me "abc/list.php?id=1" this

now if i want to fetch only the portion "?id=1" how to do that.
coz im having problems in the paging query for this.

thanxx in advance...

Comment: why don't you use `$_GET['id']` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_GET['id']` to access the id parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://php.net/parse_str, http://php.net/parse-url and http://php.net/http_build_query

Depending on what you're doing http://bradym.net/php/modify-query-string-parameters may also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

$_GET['id'] or $_REQUEST['id']

if your not sure which GET values u'll receive u also could

```
$fullRequest = exlode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$params = array();
foreach(explode('&', $fullRequest) as $part){
    foreach(explode('=', $part) as $keyVal){
        $params[$keyVal[0]] = $keyVal[1];
    }
 }
```